# Background-repeat CSS property not leaving horizontal spaces like in example, any idea why?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to follow an HTML & CSS tutorial on Youtube (https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxkQMYSa9X-wsDusL62-Xe1nfFmPPNJ8WV)

[His example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT0qK.png)

[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRTch.jpg)

[enter image description here][3]

I noticed a difference between the outcome of his code and mine, which is that in his example (the first image) there is horizontal spaces between the images, while my example (the second image) there is none despite the code being being identical on both the HTML and CSS files

So what seems to be the case?

*EDIT*
P.S.
Also the same image when I try to make it fill the container with
`background-size: cover;` property the image fills the container but it is not centered, any idea why?

```css
.small-img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9lng.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;    
}
```

```html
<div class="small-img">
  <h1>I AM SMALL IMAGE</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: space distributes space evenly if it is needed to get a whole number of images in. It looks as though the aspect ratios/dimensions of your image (and maybe the container?) is different from the tutorial’s so I wouldn’t expect the result to look the same.

Comment: @AHaworth The same image type and dimensions which 100x100.

Comment: And the container dimensions? And I note your CSS code in the question doesn’t have space. Please make a working snippet, there are too many unknowns at present.

Answer (score 0):

You can define background-image size and set background-repeat to space;
In this case, styles will fill container with images and automatically added gaps between this images.

```css
.small-img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9lng.jpg");
 
  height: 11rem;
  background-size: 5rem;
  background-repeat: space;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-img">
  <h1>I AM SMALL IMAGE</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What I don't understand why do we both have the same code with the same language and the same IDE yet different results.

Comment: Not the same image and dimensions.